# Trying to Look back 4 whole months in teradata with ADD_MONTHS function in sql statement

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to go back and retrieve counts for the last 4 full months.  This is an example of what I have so far:

`SELECT datecolumn, Count(datacolumnA) AS CountOfdatacolumnA, datacolumnB`

```
FROM tableA

WHERE datacolumnB='AA' AND datecolumn >= ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -4)
```

My results show the last four months plus the current month, October in this case.  The problem is that June isn't showing the correct count for the entire month.  I'm only getting a partial count for the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust to the start of the month. You can do this by subtracting the day of the month to get the '0th' of the month and then adding 1 to get the first. (I think dates in teradata are decimals with the int part being number of days since an epoch)

```
Select
    datecolumn, 
    Count(datacolumnA) As CountOfdatacolumnA, 
    datacolumnB
From
    tableA
Where 
    datacolumnB='AA' And
    datecolumn >= 
        add_months(current_date, -4) 
        - extract(day from add_months(current_date, -4)) + 1
```